# Getting VLC on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, vlc

I need to be able to stream media from a heroku server.  To do this I have had pretty good success using VLC on my dev system.  Now I am "ready" to deploy it to heroku, but am unsure how about how to install VLC on heroku.  Is this doable?  If so, what are the steps?  For which OS of VLC would I [download](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html#download)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is possible with Bindle: http://bindle.me/blog/index.php/405/running-binaries-on-heroku

From the article:

> Running binaries on heroku is possible if they are in the bin/ directory of your app. This is not officially supported, so use at your own risk. Heroku runs on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64bit, so you’ll want to download it to compile your program on a VM. Install Ubuntu as normal, then download the source code for the program you are interested in.

If the program has dependencies that are not standard on Ubuntu you'll need to compile them to be statically linked as described in the article.

Comment: quite the find.  Thanks.  Did you happen to come across that and this question?

Comment: Yes, I was searching for a solution to the same question and came across this page first. I found the linked page after more searching and thought it might help you out :)